# Inputting # on remote Mac through Citrix/VNC

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, vnc

I use Citrix and VNC on Win 10 to connect to my Mac at work, and I find I can't type the # symbol. I have a UK keyboard, so shift+3 produces £ (both remotely and locally), and the key marked # produces 3 on the remote machine.

No other combination of Shift or Alt or AltGr or Ctrl and 3 produces # (Alt+3, AltGr+3 and Ctrl+3 on my Windows keyboard produce nothing but the Citrix beep)

Switching keyboard layouts to US switches the £ for # locally but not remotely.

Is there another way to produce #?

Comment: The other way round, remoting to Win from Mac, I have to set the remote system's keyboard to US ...which gives me the # but at expense of the £. alt/[key] or shift/alt/[key] seems to do nothing over the remote at all.

Comment: I'd never thought of switching the layout remotely! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by switching the remote keyboard layout to US, so shift+3 produces # as expected.

This is at the expense of £, but I don't use that as often.

Comment: And I've discovered the United Kingdom (PC) setting which allows for both